# Git show file size of certain file from last 10 commits?

Tags: git, bash, shell, terminal

I want to see whether my minifying that removes debugging code is working, or it stopped working I can't tell because there are like 3 frameworks being used and code is easily over 10k lines. But I think it was working at some point. So i want to see file sizes over last 10 or so commits to see if there is huge changes in file sizes

maybe a script that takes the file size, number of commits to go back and prints the sizes from recent to old.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add error checking and perhaps not require a relative path, but you could do:

```
$ show_size() { git rev-list -10 HEAD | 
     while read sha; do git show "$sha:./$1" | wc -c; done; }
```

You might want more information; something like:

```
show_size() { git rev-list -10 HEAD |  
    while read sha; do 
        printf "%s: size %d\n" "$(git show -s --format=%aD $sha)" \
            "$(git show "$sha:./$1" | wc -c)";
    done; }
```

But, rather than checking the last 10 commits, you might just want to see when the file size changes:

```
show_size() { 
    git rev-list HEAD | while read sha; do
        printf "%s: size %d\n" "$(git show -s --format=%aD $sha)" \
            "$(git show "$sha:./$1" | wc -c)";
    done | awk '$NF!=a; {a=$NF}'
}
```

Comment: `git rev-list HEAD | sed 10q` can be `git rev-list -10 HEAD`.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log -10 --pretty='%H:path/to/it' | git cat-file --batch-check
```

will get the size of `path/to/it` in the most recent 10 commits in the checked-out history, add `--first-parent` to avoid hunting through merged-in history and `-- path/to/it` to print (and count) only commits that touched that path.

Comment: Maybe you should amend the answer to mention that one need to use the full path from the root of the repository.